# Displaying a welcome notification at login

Tags: 12.10, notification, startup-applications

I've added to **Startup Applications** this command:

```
notify-send "Hello User" "Welcome back to Ubuntu 12.10" --icon=/usr/share/unity-greeter/cof.png -a "Computer" -u critical
```

It does not appear at startup or login but works when run from terminal.

I've also tried putting the command in `/etc/rc.local`, but it doesn't work.

How can I run this command at each startup/login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why it isn't working for you, maybe because it runs before Unity is fully loaded. You could try adding a time delay using the `sleep` command.

I got it work by creating this script:

```
sleep 2s
notify-send "Hello User" "Welcome back to Ubuntu 12.10" --icon=/usr/share/unity-greeter/cof.png -a "Computer" -u critical
```

Save this to a file, set it as executable using `chmod +x <filename>` and add it to your start applications list.

If this doesn't work, try increasing the delay before the `notify-send` command runs.